# Table 'exp_accessories' already exists

Tags: database

I try to import a ee db into my local environement and I get this Error:

> SQL-Befehl:
>
> ### -- --------------------------------------------------------
>
> -- Tabellenstruktur für Tabelle `exp_accessories`
>   -- CREATE TABLE  `exp_accessories` (
>
> `accessory_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  `class`
>   VARCHAR( 75 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',  `member_groups` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT
>   NULL DEFAULT  'all',  `controllers` TEXT,  `accessory_version`
>   VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (  `accessory_id` ) ) ENGINE =
>   MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =8;
>
> MySQL meldet:
>
> ## 1050 - Table 'exp_accessories' already exists

I have absolutely no clue about db files what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the error.
The new db didn't have the same name as the old one so I deleted the lines:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci; USE `db_name`;
```

Now it works. But that's not what the error said.
Is it possible to disable this line directli in the export window of phpMysql?

Comment: How are you exporting the database?

Comment: I just go to phpmyadmin and choose export. There I choose "Save as file" and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is possibly a bug in your phpmyadmin version: http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4019/.

The create database code shouldn't be added with the default export.